# How can I find the value from another value in the same line with JavaScript (JSON)?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get the "correctAnswers" from a number.

Here a is sample of the JSON:

```
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "number": 3,
      "question": "☀️ ➕  = ?",
      "answers": [
        "sunflower",
        "BIRTHDAY",
        "iPhone",
        "MOON CAKE"
      ],
      "correctAnswers": [
        "sunflower"
      ],
      "random": true,
      "timeLimit": "24"
    },
    {
      "number": 1,
      "question": "⭐️ ➕  =❓ ",
      "answers": [
        "STAR FISH",
        "iPhone",
        "MOON CAKE",
        "HOT DOG"
      ],
      "correctAnswers": [
        "STAR FISH"
      ],
      "random": true,
      "timeLimit": "20"
    },
    {
      "number": 7,
      "question": " ➕ ☎ = ",
      "answers": [
        "SUNGLASSES",
        "SUNFLOWER",
        "HOUSEPAINT",
        "IPHONE"
      ],
      "correctAnswers": [
        "IPHONE"
      ],
      "random": true,
      "timeLimit": 15
    },
  ]
}
```

I am trying to find "number":1, OR a random number inside of the "questions" and then find the "correctAnswers" from that number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const array = {
  "questions": [
    {
      "number": 3,
      "question": "☀️ ➕  = ?",
      "answers": [
        "sunflower",
        "BIRTHDAY",
        "iPhone",
        "MOON CAKE"
      ],
      "correctAnswers": [
        "sunflower"
      ],
      "random": true,
      "timeLimit": "24"
    },
    {
      "number": 1,
      "question": "⭐️ ➕  =❓ ",
      "answers": [
        "STAR FISH",
        "iPhone",
        "MOON CAKE",
        "HOT DOG"
      ],
      "correctAnswers": [
        "STAR FISH"
      ],
      "random": true,
      "timeLimit": "20"
    },
    {
      "number": 7,
      "question": " ➕ ☎ = ",
      "answers": [
        "SUNGLASSES",
        "SUNFLOWER",
        "HOUSEPAINT",
        "IPHONE"
      ],
      "correctAnswers": [
        "IPHONE"
      ],
      "random": true,
      "timeLimit": 15
    },
  ]
};

const { questions } = array;

// Find by number
const correctAnswersByNumber = qNumber => {
  const q = questions.find(({ number }) => number === qNumber);
  if (!q) {
    return false;
  }

  return q.correctAnswers;
};
console.log(correctAnswersByNumber(3)); // Question by number === 3

// Random question
const randomCorrectAnswers = questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)].correctAnswers;
console.log(randomCorrectAnswers);
```

Comment: Works well, but if you say you're new to JS, you can not understand what the function does.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a random question using random. Then show the correct properties.

```js
var data = {
  "questions": [
    {
      "number": 3,
      "question": "☀️ ➕  = ?",
      "answers": [
        "sunflower",
        "BIRTHDAY",
        "iPhone",
        "MOON CAKE"
      ],
      "correctAnswers": [
        "sunflower"
      ],
      "random": true,
      "timeLimit": "24"
    },
    {
      "number": 1,
      "question": "⭐️ ➕  =❓ ",
      "answers": [
        "STAR FISH",
        "iPhone",
        "MOON CAKE",
        "HOT DOG"
      ],
      "correctAnswers": [
        "STAR FISH"
      ],
      "random": true,
      "timeLimit": "20"
    },
    {
      "number": 7,
      "question": " ➕ ☎ = ",
      "answers": [
        "SUNGLASSES",
        "SUNFLOWER",
        "HOUSEPAINT",
        "IPHONE"
      ],
      "correctAnswers": [
        "IPHONE"
      ],
      "random": true,
      "timeLimit": 15
    },
  ]
};


// Let's choose a random question
let question = data['questions'][Math.floor(Math.random() * data['questions'].length)];


console.log(question.question, question.correctAnswers)
```